# How to remove CRLF [http request header termination] character programatically?

Tags: penetration-test, python

I am trying to make the http request by removing the header termination character. I manually removed it by intercepting the request in proxies like burp and manually removing the header termination CRLF. I wanted to do the same using python script. I know, using 'requests' or 'urllib' packages, I can make the request and set the header. But the python libraries appends the as header termination characters. And on this append, programmer has no control. My question is how do I write script and make http request with out header termination character? 
Thanks Sanjay

Comment: I don't understand why you want to remove the linebreaks? Does your question have a security connection or is it just a programming issues you are having?

Comment: This is a pure programming question and not a security question, i.e. off-topic here.

Comment: @Anders.. I am trying to conduct the test on some application by intercepting the request in proxy. When I removed the header termination character and send the request, the application did not respond till 120 seconds. This shows that connection with server was live at least for 2 minutes. I want to take this further and automate the character removal in script. This may lead to DoS like condition similar to what pen testers do in slowloris. Hence I would like to remove the header termination character. This is the reason why I posted the question in pen tester forum as well.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich .. agree that this his pure programming query. But since it is related to pen testing, I thought of posting here with the intention that members may suggest any such tool, if already available. Thanks

Comment: @SanjayPhanshikar: *"how do I write script and make http request with out header termination character?"* - you can use a plain socket or SSL socket and write the HTTP request directly exactly as you like to the server.  These are only a few lines of code. But again, off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the CRLF is making the request incomplete and so the web server keeps the connection alive waiting for the CRLF so it can parse a complete request.

You don't have to do anything special to achieve this, just send some data that matches http syntax and doesn't end in CRLFCRLF.

As for making this a DoS you have essentially discovered nothing. You could theoretically exhaust the connection pool, but it's highly ineffective. You're better off using slowloris or a similar slow transmission attack that keeps the connection alive for a prolonged period.

Comment: … you are right. But there is a difference in slowloris and the test which I want to automate. The slowloris modes keep on sending the byte data forcing the server to keep the connection window open. In the above case, I am expecting that the server should be configured to close the connection without much of waiting. My observation of 2 minutes wait is huge. Hence the automation will help me. Thanks